# Microsoft Office Automation (Windows Desktop) Possible in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Before I go too far down this road learning Flutter and Dart, I just need to know if I'll be able to interact with Microsoft Office and other Windows desktop application SDKs. You know, like this:

Var xl = CREATEOBJECT('Excel.Application')
xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

I have searched and searched for information and can't find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: While there is nothing stopping you or other people to write windows-only packages to make this possible, I doubt the need for this is big enough that others will write this for you. Flutter is primarily used to be cross-platform and binding your app to a single platform which then even needs *another* licensed product installed on top is not really the focus.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using office automation, instead of using a package to write excel files? Quite frankly, Office Automation has so many drawbacks, even languages that can support that easily have turned away from it.